# Android crash while modifying bitmap : jni_helper.cc:110 Bitmap is of the wrong format: 4

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap, ontouch

I am working on application that allows users to shade a portion of bitmap when the swipe on it. Then when he finishes swiping I call a method to crop that portion of bitmap and perform some function(but cropped bitmap is not saved anywhere so doubt there is any problem here). On click on imageView I reset the bitmap with original bitmap. There is also a functionality to rotate the bitmap.I have two bitmap objects bill(user actually swipes on it) and billOrg(original bitmap as it is). Below are the methods.

```
private void drawShade(float left,float top,float right,float bottom){
    //this method draws shade on bitmap. Coordinates are sent from onTouchEvent
    TAG = "drawShade";
    //parseTouchPointsString();
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bill.getWidth(), bill.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Log.d(TAG,"bill:"+bill.isMutable()+"tempBit:"+tempBitmap.isMutable()+"");
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bill,0,0,null);
    tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(left,top,right,bottom), 10, 10, shadePaint);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
    if(fingerUp) {
        Log.e("fingerUp",fingerUp+"");
        bill = tempBitmap;
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"shade drawn at:"+left+","+top+","+right+","+bottom);
}
```

Here is method to rotate bitmap :

```
public void rotateImage(View v){
    TAG = "rotateImage";
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bill , 0, 0, bill.getWidth(), bill.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    bill = rotatedBitmap.copy(rotatedBitmap.getConfig(),true);
    createScaledBitmap();
    billOrg = bill.copy(rotatedBitmap.getConfig(),true);//bill.copy(bill.getConfig(),false);
    setImage(bill);

    rl.invalidate();
}
```

Method to reset bitmap on click :

```
private void resetImageView(boolean saveShade){
        //the boolean var here tell whether to keep the shaded portion after reset or not
        if(!saveShade) { //app crashes in this if block although I have try-catch.
            try {
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bill);
                Log.e("resetImageView", "billOrg:" + billOrg.isMutable() + ",bill:" + bill.isMutable()); //returns true for both bitmap objects
                canvas.drawBitmap(billOrg, 0, 0, null);
                touchBounds = "";
                tv_res.setText("");
                rl.invalidate();
                setImage(bill);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("resetImage",ex.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bill);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bill, 0, 0, null);
            touchBounds = "";
            tv_res.setText("");
            rl.invalidate();
            setImage(bill);
        }
    }
```

All is fine except when user first swipes the image --> then rotates the image --> then clicks on bitmap. 
**All I get is this error: jni_helper.cc:110 Bitmap is of the wrong format: 4**. No other exceptions.
As per my knowledge bitmaps usually throw errors if we try to modify a bitmap object which is immutable but I have made it mutable in all places. It prints mutable in logs too. I guess I am doing something wrong while modifying the bitmaps. I know might be confusing for you. I don't know how well I have explained. If you need any clarity kindly ask. I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out what was causing the problem.

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bill.getWidth(), bill.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

In the drawShade() method was culprit. I changed the "Bitmap.Config.RGB_565" to bill.getConfig() and it was fixed.